# Columns percent alignment pattern search

Tags: r, csv, pattern-matching, urlencode

In a csv file having 2 columns with below field how to get pattern match in percent along with alignment. 
Note: Values mentioned maynot be correct below. But want to know in case alignment pattern match how much correct it can be.

```
Field1  Field2  % match
aaaa    aa       66.667
bbb     ab       40
ccc     ccd      66.667
ddd     ddcv     57.142
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please, have a look at [this tutorial on how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and be more specific about what output you want and what you already tried.

Comment: Please, what are the rules to compute `% match`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to know similarity percentage between two strings then you can calculate it using 'Levenshtein Distance' or 'Jaro–Winkler distance'.

```r
library(dplyr)

#Levenshtein distance
library(RecordLinkage)
df_lv <- df %>%
  mutate(per_match = levenshteinSim(Field1, Field2))
df_lv
#  Field1 Field2 per_match
#1   aaaa     aa 0.5000000
#2    bbb     ab 0.3333333
#3    ccc    ccd 0.6666667
#4    ddd   ddcv 0.5000000
#5     aa    aas 0.6666667
#6     aa    aba 0.6666667


#Jaro–Winkler distance
library(stringdist)
df_jw <- df %>% 
  mutate(per_match = stringsim(Field1, Field2, method="jw"))
df_jw
#  Field1 Field2 per_match
#1   aaaa     aa 0.8333333
#2    bbb     ab 0.6111111
#3    ccc    ccd 0.7777778
#4    ddd   ddcv 0.7222222
#5     aa    aas 0.8888889
#6     aa    aba 0.6111111
```

```
#sample data
> dput(df)
structure(list(Field1 = c("aaaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "aa", 
"aa"), Field2 = c("aa", "ab", "ccd", "ddcv", "aas", "aba")), .Names = c("Field1", 
"Field2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**Note:** I am not sure how you calculated the percentage mentioned in your post. As @Uwe has already mentioned in the comment section you may need to let us know the algorithm you used to get these numbers so that others can help you.

Comment: I randomly calculated the values, but thing is i need the alignment also to be in the same way so based on that need the percentage accurate.

Comment: I am really not sure if I understood it. Can you pls explain the percentage calculation algorithm in your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48003035/edit)?

Comment: As in i wanted % calculations based on alignment to for eg: "aa" when compared with "aas" will be different and and "aba" will be different right

Comment: See the updated answer. You seem to be interested in [Jaro–Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance).